# SQL distinct on one column with two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am having trouble getting this query correct.  I am using Postgres and trying to query the last 15 clients viewed by a user.

Table `client`
Columns `id, name`...

Table `impressions`
Columns `imressionable_id, user_id, created_at` ...

The impressionable_id is equal to the client_id and the tables can be joined on this field.

I need to get a list of the last 15 DISTINCT client names viewed by the user and ordered DESC by the created_at date.  The problem is currently a query of the impressions table will produce many duplicate entries but with unique created_at timestamp as each time you view a client it creates a new impressions record.

So, a query of

```
select impressions.impressionable_id, created_at from impressions where user_id = 1 order by created_at DESC
```

will produce:

```
  impressionable_id   created_at
        1            2014-11-14 21:44:47.705167 
        1            2014-11-14 21:32:15.411488 
        3            2014-11-14 18:43:26.020719 
        1            2014-11-14 18:42:15.974442
        5            2014-11-14 18:41:10.609617 
        3            2014-10-29 20:53:01.383896
```

I need a query that will give me:

```
1    John Doe     2014-11-14 21:44:47.705167 
3    Jay Smith    2014-11-14 18:43:26.020719
5    Tim Jones    2014-11-14 18:41:10.609617
```

and so on.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `select max(created_at) .... group by impressionable_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MAX()` and `GROUP BY`:

```
select I.impressionable_id,c.name, MAX(I.created_at) as created_at 
from impressions JOIN
     client c ON c.id = I.user_id
group by impressionable_id,c.name
order by created_at DESC
limit 15;
```

Comment: Thanks but this gets the records from just the one table.

Comment: @RKRaider: That is because, I didn't know your table structure. Now I have updated my answer with a join.

Comment: This is my working solution with the slight exception of the join clause being on I.impressionable_id not user_id. I then added a where clause for the user_id.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT y.* FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        DISTINCT ON (x.id) x.id, x.name, x.created_at 
    FROM (SELECT c.id, c.name, i.created_at FROM clients c RIGHT JOIN impressions i ON c.id = i.user_id) x
) y 
ORDER BY y.created_at DESC LIMIT 15;
```

Comment: I gave this the answer as I was able to fix it adding the fix: c.id = i.impressionable_id where
    i.user_id =1 in lieu of c.id = i.user_id.

Comment: After careful testing this works on the first record only then it does not get the latest records for the next client ids.

Comment: @RKRaider Check the screenshot: [http://i.gyazo.com/bf4e470fbac69e330810ca5e5f7c9945.png](http://i.gyazo.com/bf4e470fbac69e330810ca5e5f7c9945.png) I created both your tables and run the query. Are you missing something saying that it doesn't work properly ?